# Performance measure of Office 365 site

Tags: performance

One Office 365 site is running with provider hosted app, but it is comparatively slow. What performance measure should be taken for it's successful running?
in fact there can be problem in the development phase also. But overall which steps to be taken?

Comment: check out this video http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/office-365-performance-management